# Set jQuery Function variables from outside function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working with the jQuery ProcessBar [custom label version]. I'm making it so I can check the values inside. I care about the percentage of the bar and the text that is displayed. I can change these values from inside the function. Notice the "progress(15);" and the "progressLabel.text("text");"

I would like to change these from in my body. How can I do this?

I'm also a little confused on the code, because originally this was a complete function. Meaning that they built it to show off. So when you ran the page it automatically went from 0 to 100 percent and complete. My goal is to control it.

```
$(function() 
{
    var progressbar = $( "#progressbar" ),
    progressLabel = $( ".progress-label" );

    progressbar.progressbar(
    {
        value: false,
        change: function() 
        {
            progressLabel.text( progressbar.progressbar( "value" ) );
        },
        complete: function() 
        {
            progressLabel.text( "Complete!" );
        }
    });

    function progress(val) 
    {
        progressbar.progressbar( "value", val );

        if ( val < 99 ) 
        {    
            setTimeout( progress, 100 );
        }
    }

    progress(15);
    progress(20);
    progress(99);
    progressLabel.text("text");
    setTimeout( progress, 3 );
});
```

Right now I'm trying:

```
$('#progressbar').progressLabel.text('text');
```

It's worth mentioning, that I am very new to jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pretty close. What you're trying to do, though, is pass an argument to the progress function, but it doesn't use any arguments. Modify the function to look like this:

```
function progress (newValue) {
    progressbar.progressbar("value", newValue);
}
```

Then you put in arbitrary values like this:

```
progress(15);
progress(20);
progress(90);
// Change the label
progressLabel.text("text");
progress(99);
// Progress label will automatically change to "Complete!"
progress(100);
```

These will run immediately, so you'll need to comment them out line by line and reload the page to see a difference.

I also removed both setTimeout calls, as the first one was used for demo purposes, and yours simply started the demo function.